# What listed Wildfly-BOM dependencies are not loaded by default by Wildfly, and needs to be manually added in the standalone?

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly

Most of our maven dependencies are `<scope>provided</scope>` because they are provided/supplied by Wildfly. And we use the Wildfly-BOM to check what dependencies are provided/supplied by Wildfly:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly.bom/wildfly-ee -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
   <artifactId>wildfly-ee</artifactId>
   <version>31.0.0.Final</version>
   <scope>import</scope>
   <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

However, after having issues with the deployment not finding any `org/apache/http` classes, we discovered that `org.apache.httpcomponents` wasn't loaded by default, and needed to be manually added in the `standalone.xml`:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:6.0">
   <global-modules>
      <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents"/>
   </global-modules>
   ...
</subsystem>
```

Why isn't `org.apache.httpcomponents` loaded by default even if it is listed in the Wildfly-BOM?

Are there any other dependencies listed in the Wildfly-BOM that also needs to be manually added to the `standalone.xml`?

I tried searching for a list and/or reason for why some dependencies needed to be manually added, but found no Wildfly/Red Hat resource, where in the documentation is this explained?

Answer (score 0):

The BOM is for Maven usage to help manage your dependencies for your project. It has nothing to do with the servers configuration and JBoss Modules.

Adding there are few ways to add module dependencies to your deployment. Have a look at the [class loading documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/31/Developer_Guide.html#Class_Loading_in_WildFly).

The `standalone.xml` snippet you've included does not look correct to me. You cannot use the `module` element there. It would need to be wrapped in a `<global-modules>` tag.

Comment: Sorry, the `<global-modules>` was just missing from my example. My understanding is that Wildfly will provide a stack of dependencies. Found in the wildfly-31.0.0.Final/module catalogue. These dependecies does not need to be added to the built artifact, so they can be of scope `<scope>provided</scope>`. However, it does not look like `<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>` are loaded by wildfly by default, and needs to be added to the `<global-modules>. Not sure why this only is the case with `<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>`. Will have to read your class loading doc.

Comment: With that specific module, it's best to package  a version in your application. It's a private module meaning it could go away at any time.`<property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>` is in the `module.xml` file.